# HtmlUnit submitbuttonClick is not working, it works in my apache tomcat and not in the client

Tags: java, button, htmlunit

It works fine for me but when i am trying to run it on clients server it is not clicking button. if it clicks than i don't know what happen it will not redirect on the second page. i get same page not the second page i have make do while loop for click it around 10 times but it will not work it works very good in my system. please help me to sort out this.. i am very confused on this. don't know what is wrong..and if code is wrong than it would be not run in my system but it works perfectly.

Comment: Please post your source code, and if possible an url to try it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `click()` method, this won't affect on the current `HtmlPage` object, but it returns a new instance of `HtmlPage`. What you need is to assign the new instance to the existing `HtmlPage` reference:

```
page = button.click();
```

or assign it to a new reference:

```
HtmlPage page2 = button.click();
```

Comment: Sorry for this it is not work for me cause i have exactly same done in my code..  submitFormPage = sumbitButtton.click();

Comment: Depending of the page, click() method could not work without tricks, and somtimes could never work. eg : Javascript may need to be enabled, if the click is to validate a form and cant perform weel, you can forge the request and POST it directly ... we need more info about your code and the page please.

Comment: I have enable javascript and when it runs in my machine it works perfectly. but it is not working on client machine.